# Can I use variable that inculding a URL image link in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

```
  var res = "https://i.imgur.com/IQi699Z.jpg"
  var el = document.getElementById("image");
  el.innerHTML='<img src=res>'
```

Comment: could you reformulate your question to explain what is your problem, what you've tried to solve it, what you want to do ...

Comment: `el.src = res;` is this what you are trying to do? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "image" element is a container (`<div id="image"></div>`)

```js
var res = "https://i.imgur.com/IQi699Z.jpg";
var el = document.getElementById("image");
el.innerHTML = '<img src="' + res + '" />';
```

If your "image" element is already an "img" tag (`<img id="image"/>`)

```js
var res = "https://i.imgur.com/IQi699Z.jpg";
var el = document.getElementById("image");
el.src = res;
```